# why it is giving false every time while comparing dates?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to compare dates .I am getting false for every condition  . If second date is  above from first   it should show above date  . If second date is equal to first it show  equal dates .if second date is below the first it show below date

Here is my code 
https://jsfiddle.net/5Lps5zxh/1/

```
var first="22-3-2015"
var second="01-3-2015";
alert(new Date(first).getTime() > new Date(second).getTime())

if( (new Date(first).getTime() > new Date(second).getTime()))
{
    alert('--')
}
```

it is giving me false on every time

Comment: When using `new Date` your string must be in [a valid format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#ECMAScript_5_ISO-8601_format_support). For example `new Date("22-3-2015")` on my browser returns `Invalid Date`. Use something like [momentJS](http://momentjs.com/) instead to parse an exact format

Comment: [Your first date is invlid](https://jsfiddle.net/5Lps5zxh/2/), @RGraham said.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/5Lps5zxh/4/). (**`MM-DD-YYYY`**)
Check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/5Lps5zxh/11/). (**`YYYY-MM-DD`**) **(RECOMMENDED)**

Use **`MM-DD-YYYY`** or **`YYYY-MM-DD`** format and you'll have **NO** issues.

Here is the snippet. (**`MM-DD-YYYY`**)

```js
var first = "03-22-2015" //MM-DD-YYYY
var second = "03-01-2015"; //MM-DD-YYYY
alert(new Date(first).getTime() + " ---- " + new Date(second).getTime());
alert(new Date(first).getTime() > new Date(second).getTime())

if ((new Date(first).getTime() > new Date(second).getTime())) {
  alert('--')
}
```

Here is the snippet. (**`YYYY-MM-DD`**)

```js
var first = "2015-03-22" //YYYY-MM-DD
var second = "2015-03-01"; //YYYY-MM-DD
alert(new Date(first).getTime() + " ---- " + new Date(second).getTime());
alert(new Date(first).getTime() > new Date(second).getTime())

if ((new Date(first).getTime() > new Date(second).getTime())) {
  alert('--')
}
```

Comment: Great, I just wanted to comment that the year doesn't have 22 months :) but you were faster.

Comment: Right idea, but c'mon we're computer scientists, we should be recommending YYYY-MM-DD it is better in every way!

Comment: @trex005 Right, YYYY-MM-DD is the preferred and the best way. It is also  ISO standard: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: @trex005 Updated my answer. Included both formats. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 3):

If you try `alert(new Date(first));`, it says that it's an invalid date. When you then do `.getTime()`, it returns `NaN` which is never greater than the other time.

Comment: so what is better solution to compare date ?

Comment: Your solution is fine, the error is in trying to parse a date that is not in a format that `new Date(...)` understands. Look at `Date.parse()` to see what format it accepts: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Answer (score 1):

This is from console:

```
new Date('22-3-2015').getTime() 
NaN
```

That's why it is false.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a date variable instead of attempting to cast one,

I have created a jsFiddle to show you

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/uc9csxk2/

Javascript

```
var dates = "22-3-2015";
var result = new Date(dates);
alert(result);

var first = new Date(2015,3,22);
var second = new Date(2015,3,1);

alert(first.getTime() > second.getTime())

if( first.getTime() > second.getTime())
{
    alert('--')
}
```

Basically your date string "22-3-2015" is an invalid date.

Answer (score 0):

The following code returns true:

```
var first="11-13-2015"
var second="10-10-2015";
alert(new Date(first).getTime() > new Date(second).getTime())
```

Why?

The Date format is MM-DD-YYYY, so in the above case it returns true

Answer (score 0):

Assuming European date (dd-mm-yyyy) and also assuming you cannot change them to the preferred yyyy-mm-dd, you could do this to make the dates parse proper

```js
var first = "22-3-2015"
var second = "01-3-2015";

function makeDate(str) {
  var parts = str.split("-");
  return new Date(parts[2], parts[1] - 1, +parts[0])
}
alert(makeDate(first) +">"+ makeDate(second))

if ((makeDate(first).getTime() > makeDate(second).getTime())) {
  alert('--')
}
```